# Why is my React application not updating on my custom domain after successful deployment to Cloudflare Pages?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

I have deployed a React application to Cloudflare pages successfully. When I navigate to the new deployment link, the application is updated with new version changes, but when I navigate to the custom domain that was set up, I see an old version of the application. I tried with clearing the cache via `purge cache` but there was no effect. How do I fix this ?